# Content Provider filtering query, filtering Cursor

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider

I got following problem, I need to use a Content Provider to read a
Database of an other App.
first I want all rows, and after analyzing the data only e.g. the rows
from _id = 1, 3 and 5.

how can I call a Content provider and select only these rows?

or is it possible to create a subset Cursor form an given Cursor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking to another app, I assume you're querying the other app's ContentProvider to get the data from them in the first place.

In this situation, the cleanest answer seems not to build your own ContentProvider that filters/wraps theirs.  Instead query their ContentProvider from your application directly, and use the select clause in your query() to specify the conditions that define the subset of data you want to be given.